Find the slope of the curve $e^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y})=x+\frac{1}{y}$ at $(e, \frac{1}{e})$.
The problem:
Find the slope of the curve $e^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y})=x+\frac{1}{y}$ at $(e, \frac{1}{e})$.
The solution:
$-\frac{1}{e^2}$
What I have tried:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y}))=\frac{d}{dx}(x+\frac{1}{y}) \iff e^{xy} \cdot \frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}} \cdot (\frac{y\cdot1-x\cdot1\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2})+\ln(\frac{x}{y})\cdot e^{xy}\cdot(x\cdot1\frac{dy}{dx}+y)=1-y^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx}\iff e^{xy}\cdot\frac{y}{x}\cdot (\frac{y-x\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2})+\ln(\frac{x}{y})\cdot e^{xy}(y+x\frac{dy}{dx})=1-\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}$$
My question:
I do not know how to continue on from here. I know that at some point I am to plug the coordinates $(e, \frac{1}{e})$ inside the function I get. Possibly when I get $\frac{dy}{dx}$ alone on one side. How do I continue to get just that?

You're on the right track.  Implicitly differentiate the equation (as you have already done), and solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to get:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^2(x - e^{xy} - xye^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y}))}{x(1 - ye^{xy} + xy^2e^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y}))}$$
Then, just plug in $x = e$ and $y = \frac{1}{e} = e^{-1}$, to get:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{e^{-2}(e - e^{1} - 1e^{1}\ln(\frac{e}{1/e}))}{e(1 - e^{-1}e^{1} + ee^{-2}e^{1}\ln(\frac{e}{1/e}))}$$
$$= -\frac{1}{e^2}$$

$e^{xy} \cdot \frac{y-x\frac{dy}{dx}}{xy}+\ln(\frac{x}{y})e^{xy}(y+x\frac{dy}{dx})+\frac{1}{y^2} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=1 \iff e^{xy}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx})+e^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y}) \cdot y + e^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y}) \cdot x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{y^2} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=1 \iff \frac{e^{xy}}{x}-\frac{e^{xy}}{y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+e^{xy}y\ln(\frac{x}{y})+\frac{dy}{dx}(e^{xy}x\ln(\frac{x}{y})+\frac{1}{y^2})=1 \iff \frac{dy}{dx}(xe^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y})+\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{e^{xy}}{y})=1-\frac{e^{xy}}{x}-ye^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y})$

This is what I get when I try to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. I'm not heading towards the right direction, right? I'm not gonna get what you got.

$\iff \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-\frac{e^{xy}}{x}-ye^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y})}{xe^{xy}\ln(\frac{x}{y})+\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{e^{xy}}{y}}$. Is this right? It doesn't match what you got, which means I still cannot put my coordinates in to get the slope. How did you get your $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

@Sien: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $xy^2$ to get rid of the nested fractions.

You are very close to the end.
Substitute $x=e$ and $y=\frac1e$ into your final equation and simplify so you have an equation for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ which you can solve to give the answer. You get $$e^1\cdot e^{-2}\cdot \left({e^{-1}-e\frac{dy}{dx}}\right)e^2+\ln(e^2)\cdot e^{1}(e^{-1}+e\frac{dy}{dx})=1-e^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$
i.e.
$$1 -e^2\frac{dy}{dx}+2+2\cdot e^{2}\frac{dy}{dx}=1-e^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$
which becomes $2+2\cdot e^{2}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$ and so $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{1}{e^2}$ as expected.
I think it is also worth checking $(e,\frac1e)$ actually lies on the curve.  Since $e\times \log(e^2)=2e=e+\frac1{\frac1e}$, it does.
